# Read MySQL database based on primary key using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

My code doesn't seem to work. I'm using the following:

```
$statement   = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM carts WHERE (order_id = ':order_id')");
$result      = $statement->execute(array(':order_id' => $order_id));
$result      = $statement->fetch();
```

Which returns a boolean according to `gettype($result)`; `print_r($result)` simply displays Array, though this is not expected. The data I'm reading is:

[image: My Data]

So I should expect an Array to be returned, not a Boolean. The PDO is correct and working, as I can call a write command. What's the best way using PDO to read a row based on the Primary Key `order_id` into a parsable array?

And as a split, is there a more efficient way than `SELECT * WHERE` to read a single row of data from a `TABLE` when the data is based on the `Primary Key`?

Comment: Don't put quotes round a bind variable, PDO does that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before all, set properly your error mode. If you can run the query with single quotes without an error popping, set this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM carts WHERE order_id=:order_id");
$result = $statement->execute(array(':order_id' => $order_id));
$row = ($result ? $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : array('problem' => 'with your query'));
print_r($result);
```

PDO fails with single-quotes around parameters. check your `$result` for the return value of `execute()`. you may have to specify a fetching mode for the fetch. depending on your sql database, parenthesis around the condition may also cause the query to fail.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks heaps! The only thing is, it hasn't changed anything, I'm still getting the same result. I've implemented your suggestion though, much appreciated.

Comment: can you post what you do with `$result` after?

Comment: I treat it as an array with keys; the processing code is fairly long, but if I call 'print_r($result);' for instance, I get an empty 'Array()' printed to the screen after implementing both of the answers provided to me by you guys, when I expect the Array to be populated by the row data.

Answer (score 1):

you have to store the result in somewhere, add:

`$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

next to `$result      = $statement->fetch();` to store in `$rows` the data returned

Comment: This is interesting Pablo; my original function (before PDO) used `mysqli_fetch_array()`. I inserted your answer on the next line, and now I'm getting an empty array. Much better! But still not particularly useful LOL. Any ideas as to why I'd be getting an empty array? I assume that would happen if `order_id` didn't exist in the database; but the thing is, it does.